# Symfony PHPUnit with Zenstruck-Foundry creates database/table twice

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpunit

I've just installed PHP-unit on a new app and it is throwing an error when I attempted to execute `php bin/phpunit` for the first time.

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists:

I use `zenstruck-foundry` to reset the database, as below, but it does not seem to work properly.

/tests/CustomApiTestCase

```
 namespace App\Tests;

 use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
 use Zenstruck\Foundry\Test\Factories;
 use Zenstruck\Foundry\Test\ResetDatabase;

 class CustomApiTestCase extends ApiTestCase
 {
   use Factories;
   use ResetDatabase;
   .....
```

Which then extends the test script:

/tests/Api/CustomApiRoutesTest

```
 <?php

  namespace App\Tests\Api;

  use App\Tests\CustomApiTestCase;

  class CustomApiRoutesTest extends CustomApiTestCase
```

I did verify that the test database is created when I execute `php bin/phpunit`, but it would seem that the reset database from `zenstruck-foundry` is not being executed.

And then it somehow tries to create de database once again and, of course, it fails.